# How to rename git branch name

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to rename my git branch name from b1 to c1 (for example)

note: I don't want to create a copy from old branch

Can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

Use from this code in your terminal:

```
git branch -m old_name new_name
```

by example:

```
git branch -m b1 c1
```

Comment: you are self-answer your question? but I think that command still `copy from old branch`